# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED node.js (express) and express-http-proxy

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy

There was a problem making me crazy. For the third day I fight over it. There are two files, app.js and api.js

// app.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

app.use('/api', proxy('http://localhost:1234'));

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

//api.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/bookshop');

var Users = require('./models/users');
```

Below in the file, there is a usual treatment to routes...

At the end of api.js, it is indicated that this script is being listened on port 1234:

```
app.listen(1234, err => {
  if (err) console.log(err);

  console.log('worked on http://localhost:1234');
});
```

Inside api.js there should be an access to the routes and to the database, but it does not reach the point of contact, because when I access the site I get the following:

```
"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1234"
```

This message returns this middleware from app.js:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
   console.log(err.message);
});
```

In package.json in "scripts" I indicated that the server app.js (3000 port) and the server api.js (1234 port) would be launched, but when updating the page on the site, occurs appeal to the address localhost:3000/api/users, but not localhost:1234/api/user, how it should be.

Help overcome this misfortune! There are no forces at all, I scoured the whole Internet in search of a solution to the problem , but the solution to the problem has not been found...

P.S. On the work computer this code works fine, but at home flatly refuses. At work x32 windows 8.1, at home x64 windows 8.1, if this is important.

```
netstat -a | findstr LISTEN
```

returns this: https://ibb.co/hyrxe5 (link to screenshot).

I also wanted to add that if I run the scripts separately, i.e. in one terminal call "node app.js" and in the second "node api.js", everything works fine

What is the problem? (sorry for my ugly english)

Comment: How do you run the scripts? In same terminal? With what command?

Comment: I observed your post. As you mentioned in app.js app.use('/api', proxy('http://localhost:1234')); means app.js is running on port 1234. And next you mentioned  At the end of api.js, it is indicated that this script is being listened on port 1234. Means both the server codes are running on same port. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Not exactly. App.js is listening on the port 3000, and api.js on 1234

Comment: notanormie, I run scripts through the nodemon command. In package.json the following is written down: "node app & node api"

Comment: All thanks very much for the feedback, guys
I found my error, and it was in the package.json file: where I needed to write in the "scripts" property: "node app.js & node api.js", I wrote "node app.js & api.js "
To blame, as usual, the usual inattention = (
Thanks again, and good coding!